# Problem with "pkcs11.h" when running with "go build" or "go run main.go"

Tags: c, go, cgo, pkcs#11

I'm making a CGO code that uses PKCS11 and after enabling CGO and some errors, tests and corrections I've found a new error that I never seen. It doesn't matter if I use "go build" or "go run main.go", the error still appears.
Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/miekg/pkcs11"
)

func main() {
    p := pkcs11.New("aetpkss1.dll")
    err := p.Initialize()

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer p.Destroy()
    defer p.Finalize()

    slots, err := p.GetSlotList(true)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    session, err := p.OpenSession(slots[0], pkcs11.CKF_SERIAL_SESSION|pkcs11.CKF_RW_SESSION)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer p.CloseSession(session)

    err = p.Login(session, pkcs11.CKU_USER, "1234")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer p.Logout(session)

    p.DigestInit(session, []*pkcs11.Mechanism{pkcs11.NewMechanism(pkcs11.CKM_SHA_1, nil)})
    hash, err := p.Digest(session, []byte("this is a string"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, d := range hash {
        fmt.Printf("%x", d)
    }

    fmt.Println()
}
```

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Teste2> go run main.go
# runtime/cgo
cc1.exe: error: C:\src\github.com\miekg\pkcs11\pkcs11.h: not a directory [-Werror]
cc1.exe: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Comment: Never use filename arguments to go run, especially not if you are having troubles or do not understand what you are doing.

Comment: But it's a rule in golang to put the filename after go run to work

Comment: "But it's a rule in golang to put the filename after go run to work" Wherever you read this ir learned this: Stop consulting this resource. (There is no such rule, it actually is _very_ bad practice.)

Comment: Hi, have you tried `go build main`?

Comment: Yes. Didn't work

Answer (score 2):

You need install the package pkcs11, you can this command

```html
go get -u github.com/miekg/pkcs11
```

and you need have aetpkss1.dll PKCS#11 library available on your system. And it's in the correct location and properly installed.

Check that the environment variables CGO_ENABLED and CC are correctly set. You might need to set these variables to specify the C compiler to use and enable CGO. For Exemple:

```html
export CGO_ENABLED=1
export CC=gcc
```

Comment: Hello, I already installed the pkcs11 package, enabled the CGO and I put the aetpkss1.dll library inside the project directory.
But the problem is still happening. I didn't do these exports, where I put them in the code? Or in the terminal?